Trouble fitting a polynomial to a short series of data in R
I am trying to fit a polynomial or loess to a short series of data (crop coefficient (Kc) ~ growing degree days (gdds)).  The actual data is quite short, where
Kc <- c(0.1, 0.41, 0.54, 0.66, 0.85, 1)
gdd <- c(0, 90, 225, 270, 360, 630)

In order to produce smooth ends, I am putting 3 of these data sets together as follows.
Kc <- c(0.1, 0.41, 0.54, 0.66, 0.85, 1, 1.1, 1.41, 1.54, 1.66, 1.85, 2, 2.1, 2.41, 2.54, 2.66, 2.85, 3)
gdd <- c(0, 90, 225, 270, 360, 630, 630, 720, 855, 900, 990, 1260, 1260, 1350, 1485, 1530, 1620, 1890)
df <- data.frame(gdd = gdd, Kc = Kc)

A typical polynomial fit in R would look like:
Kc_fit <- lm(Kc ~ poly(gdd,4))

These results are quite poor, however, and increasing the degree of the polynomial does not make a big difference.
ggplot(df, aes(x=gdd, y=Kc)) + geom_point() + stat_smooth(method='lm', formula = Kc ~ poly(gdd,4), size = 1)

The above ggplot code produces strange results that I can't make sense of.  Not sure why it would do so.  Otherwise, does anyone have any ideas that would allow me to fit a smooth polynomial, loess, or other fit to the data (where the fit goes through the points and the amount of smoothing is minimal)?
I haven't run across this issue in R before, and its kind of strange that it's having trouble fitting a polynomial to this data.  Thanks.

A polynomial fit is completely different from a smoothing (or loess) fit.  What do you really want?      BTW,   it is almost never a good idea to increase the polynomial degree in an attempt to "improve" the fit.

Plot the data: Since your "repeated data" are linear expansions, you've already forced a linear fit to be the best.   Without knowing the expected error bars on your admittedly tiny source data,  you probably can't do better than linear or possibly y = k*sqrt(x) fit.

What do you mean by "putting three of these datasets together as follows"? Have you tried plotting your data and looking at it? There are barely enough points to fit a quadratic although a plausible cubic fit is just about possible. Go beyond that you will get increasingly "better" fits to the points at the expense of wild oscillations in between the constraint points. This isn't any fault of R it is intrinsic to using polynomial fits. poly(gdd,3) if you must, poly(gdd,2) would be a more cautious solution.

This looks pretty good with the original (not extended) data and has only 2 parameters:  fm <- nls(Kc ~ A - exp(-B * gdd), df, start = list(A = 1, B = .001)); plot(df); lines(fitted(fm) ~ gdd, df)

See my reply below.  Also, I know that loess is different from a polynomial.  I was getting at the question of which would work better.  In this case, it is appropriate to fit the data as closely as possible, as this model will not be used to predict on different data sets.

I'm not sure what you mean by "quite poor":
Kc_fit <- lm(Kc ~ poly(gdd,4), df)
summary(Kc_fit)

Residual standard error: 0.1032 on 13 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9898,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9866 

(On the other hand, a simple linear model (Kc ~ gdd) has a multiple R^2 of 0.9873 and an adjusted R^2 of 0.9865, so adding the polynomial terms doesn't do much -- although there is a 2.1 unit improvement in AIC for the 4th-order model ...)
The problem with your plot (not the model itself) is that the formula for stat_smooth always has to be specified in terms of x and y, not the original variables from the data frame, i.e. in this case stat_smooth(method='lm', formula = y ~ poly(x,4)):


For what it's worth, the quadratic fit to your original data set (as others have pointed out, your method of 'extending' the data set seems a little fishy and may introduce unwanted artifacts) seems pretty good:

You can use a polynomial to get a line that is as close to the points as possible: here I show polynomials with order 2, 4, and 5 (the order-5 polynomial interpolates the points exactly, but the confidence intervals can't even be computed).
Something like a monotonic interpolation spline might be a sensible approach ... but any further questions about the best way to model these data definitely belong on Cross Validated rather than here.
library(ggplot2); theme_set(theme_bw())
ggplot(df, aes(x=gdd, y=Kc)) +
    stat_smooth(method='lm', formula = y ~ poly(x, 2), col = "red", fill = "red") +
    stat_smooth(method='lm', formula = y ~ poly(x, 4), col = "blue", fill = "blue") +
    stat_smooth(method='lm', formula = y ~ poly(x, 5), col = "orange", fill = "orange") +
    geom_point(size = 3)



The reason I say "quite poor" is that crops grow in specific stages, each of which is accompanied by a specific change in crop coefficient.  So, it would be nice to be able to fit a polynomial that would be as close to these values as possible.  I am aware that, statistically speaking, the fits look very good.  But, from a physical perspective, it would be nice if the fit would match the given points more closely.
